# stray end tag - invalid mark up with <span>

Tags: html

Can anyone see the problem here?

I have checked the entire code and can not figure out the solution to these issues I am getting:

---

Error Line 119, Column 46: End tag h3 seen, but there were open elements.

```
<h3> BoostWorks <span> /Webdesign/</h3> </span>
```

✉
Error Line 119, Column 29: Unclosed element span.

#### BoostWorks  /Webdesign/

Answer (score 1):

Your html is malformed, you have an h3 end tag in between span tags, it should be

```
<h3> BoostWorks <span> /Webdesign/ </span></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `<span>` before you close the `<h3>`.  You can't have opening and closing tags overlapping like that.

```
<h3> BoostWorks <span> /Webdesign/</span></h3>
```